# How to control DataTable to CSV toString() formatting?

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, tostring

I had a small app working fine on my machine, where i was able to fetch data from a MySQL db to a DataTable then write that DataTable to CSV without problems, then someone tried to run this on their machine and the and the datetime column started to have different behaviour than expected:
on my machine i have something like this:**(which is what i want)**

```
2015-11-14 00:00:00,  
2015-11-14 00:01:00, 
2015-11-14 00:02:00, 
2015-11-14 00:03:00,
```

But on another machine i had:

```
15/07/2015 4:40:55 PM,  
15/07/2015 4:41:56 PM,  
15/07/2015 4:42:55 PM,  
15/07/2015 4:43:55 PM,  
15/07/2015 4:44:56 PM,
```

My code is:

```
    try
    {
        lock (writtingLock)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
            dataTable = newMyDataTable;
            fileId = dataTable.TableName;
            PathMaker path = new PathMaker(fileId);
            path.Make();
            // writing the table to a file
            using (StreamWriter swr =
                new StreamWriter(File.Open(path.filePath, FileMode.Create), Encoding.Default, 1000000))
            // change buffer size and Encoding to your needs
            {
                if (addHeader)
                {
                    foreach (var dc in dataTable.Columns)
                    {
                        swr.Write(dc.ToString() + ",");
                    }
                    swr.WriteLine();
                }
                foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    Object[] test = dr.ItemArray;
                    test.Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(DateTime)).Select(t => (DateTime)t).Select(x => x.ToFileTime());
                    swr.WriteLine(string.Join(",", test.Select(x => x.ToString().TrimEnd(null)).ToArray()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

adding or removing the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");` has no effect, how can i fix this problem ? is there anyway to control the formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
swr.WriteLine(string.Join(",", test.Select(x => x.ToString().TrimEnd(null)).ToArray()));
```

Look at the `x.ToString()` expression.

.Net is using overload resolution to know that it needs to call [`DateTime.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx). The documentation for this method includes the following:

> This method uses formatting information derived from the current culture. In particular, it combines the custom format strings returned by the ShortDatePattern and LongTimePattern

In other words, the other computer has different date formatting options than yours.

You started to account for this by setting the thread culture earlier in the code. However, if I set my own system to use the `en-CA` culture, but then also customize the date/time formatting on my machine, applying the `en-CA` culture to a thread still uses my customized date-time format, because that's what I've said `en-CA` should look like on this system.

You may not like it, but this is a perfectly normal thing that, as programmers, we're supposed to account for in advance when we need precise formatting. As it appears you do need a precise format, you'll need to adjust this code to be smart enough to know the difference between date types and other types, so that you can specify the precise format you need.

You'll want to do the same thing for numeric types (`int`, `float`, `decimal`, `single`, `double`, etc), because those types can also have output that varies by the system's current culture settings.

There is one shortcut. You could use the `InvariantCulture`. However, this will only work when the InvariantCulture happens to have the formatting that you want. If you need something different, you're back to handling individual types. Sometimes, though, the InvariantCulture can be a useful starting point. It may be correct for numbers, for example, such that you only need to provide your format for dates.

Finally, while I'm here, I wanted to call the out the preceding line of code:

```
test.Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(DateTime)).Select(t => (DateTime)t).Select(x => x.ToFileTime());
```

*That code has no effect!*  It doesn't assign back to your `test` variable, and so any work it does (which, thankfully, isn't much, as the Enumerators are never executed) would just be thrown away. You should probably just remove this line.

Comment: I have questions, can you give me an example of how to test for these "dangerous" types and handle them? that last line of code that you say is useless, how can it be fixed to format datetime? How come the enumerator is not executed?

Comment: An enumerator just creates a state machine that knows how to loop over the original collection. You need to either use an actual `foreach` loop or an extension method like `.ToArray()`, `.ToLis()`, `.All()`, `.Count()`, or `.Any()` that returns a result other than another enumerator.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime::ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )`.